# Highcharts 3D Pie

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I drew a pie chart with `highcharts`, but in 3D mode my labels are separated from the chart.
You can see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andynedine/8cK3M/3/). 
If you change `x` and `y` values from `dataLabels` and run the example, you get the same result. The labels aren´t moved. Why? Do I need to define any parameter? With normal mode It works, but with 3D mode....BREAK!!

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 45,
                beta: 0
            }
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Test'
        },
        tooltip : {
            pointFormat: 'Value: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'    
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                depth: 35,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    format: '{point.name}',
                    connectorWidth: 5,
                    x:100,
                    y:300
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Test - Levels',
            data: [
                ['Some Text Level 1', 74.25], 
                ['Some Text Level 2', 17.82], 
                ['Some Text Level 3', 7.92]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

**UPDATED:**

Bug found in `HighCharts v4.0.1`

BUG FIXED in `HIGHCHARTS v4.0.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforuantely it is known bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3082

Please stay on track with the github thread, until publish a fix.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll stay on track

Comment: Bug fixed. New version HighCharts 4.0.3 available

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix the label position.

Try it:

```
pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                depth: 35,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}',
                    connectorWidth: 5
                }
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cK3M/8/